# How to navigate to URL without full reload using page.js?

Tags: page.js

I want to redirect the user after submitting a form without reloading the page (document).

I tried,

```
page("./newurl/18/meetings");
```

---

When I click on a link `<a href="./newurl/18/meetings">link</a>` it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out. It simply reloads the page when using a relative link with a leading dot.

**This will reload**

```
page("./mypath/subpath");
```

**This will work properly**

```
page("/mypath/subpath");
```